# CakePHP Pagination with hasMany through Relationship

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a model relationship like this:

```
Person belongsTo Counselor, PersonType, Program, Term
Person hasMany PersonStage, Text, Mail
PersonStage belongsTo Person, Stage
Stage hasMany PersonStage
```

Essentially, I have created a many-to-many relationship between stage and person, but the PeronStage table `(people_stages)` has some extra information, most importantly a `created` field.

What I am attempting to do is find and paginate results, often based on the Person's *current* PersonStage, which would always be the most recent (one with `MAX(people_stages.created)`.)

I have no idea how to accomplish this in Cake. I know in SQL the join query would be as follows, but I have no idea how to replicate this in Cake.

```
SELECT   *
FROM     people AS p LEFT JOIN (people_stages AS s NATURAL JOIN (
           SELECT   person_id, MAX(created) created
           FROM     people_stages
           GROUP BY person_id
         ) t) ON s.person_id = p.id
ORDER BY p.last_name
```

I have tried various joins, all to no avail. Here is my code without these joins:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'recursive' => -1,
    'contain' => array('Counselor','Term','Program','PersonType'), 
    'fields' => array('Person.*', 'Counselor.id', 'Counselor.first_name', 'Counselor.last_name', 'Term.*', 'Program.*', 'PersonType.*'),
    'order' => array('Person.counselor_read' => 'asc', 'PersonStage.create' => 'desc'),
    'limit' => 25
);
$people = $this->Paginator->paginate('Person');
```

Answer (score 0):

Before getting results in pagination you should follow some criteria like this

Declare `$paginate` variable in your controller i.e. `PeopleController`

```
public $paginate = array(
    'limit' => 10, // you can set how much you want
    'order' => 'People.last_name'
);
```

and then in your action of `PeopleController` where you want to paginate the results just set the conditions to fetch the data in the way you want,

```
public function your_action_name() {
    $this->paginate['contain'] = array('PersonStage');
    $this->Person->Behaviors->load('Containable');
    $people = $this->paginate();
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. I need to keep the pagination settings inside the method because they are different -- this is on the admin side, versus the public side which has different requirements. The pagination is working, it's just the join I can't figure out.

Comment: Are you using containable behavior for your model? if not load it in your action by 
`$this->Person->Behaviors->load('Containable');`

Comment: Yes, definitely using Containable. The problem is, though, that I'd like to select the most recent stage, not all stages that the user has ever had.

Comment: Don't you want the results by grouping of `person.id`, if so Need to think for it.